# Javafx stage is null

Tags: java, javafx, initialization, scene, stage

I have two controllers here `authcontroller` and `maincontroller`. Method register opens new window - register.fxml.

```
register.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                AnchorPane pane = null;
                try {
                    pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/register.fxml"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                stage.setTitle("Регистрация в системе");
                Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 450);
                stage.setResizable(false);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
            }
        });
```

And then in second controller I have method initialize, where I try to get `Stage` from first window.

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)  {
    Stage stage = (Stage) tabOnePane.getScene().getWindow();

}
```

`tabOnePane` is tabpane from second window. But when I try to do this, my `Stage` is always null. But if I try to get `Stage` inside another handle-method I can do it. How to get `Stage` of first window when my second window has loaded?

second controller implements interface `Initializable`

Comment: It's a bad idea to do this. If you're getting the `Window` in the initialize method, you rely on `tabOnePane` being  added to a scene and that scene being added to a window. This makes the code hard to maintain. You should probably find a way to do whatever you're doing with that `stage` from outside of the controller class. How did you manage to add `tabOnePane` to a scene before you finished loading the fxml anyways?

Comment: I've added tabOnePane from fxml-file, using fx:id. Unfortunately, I need to use this stage in that class, because it gives me property I use later in second class.

Answer (score 0):

first you never cant access to stage in initialize method in Controller.
second just add a method to controller like setStage(Stage stge) then load fxml like this to pass stage to controller:

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/root/mainGui.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 400);
    controllerInterface ctrl = loader.getController();
    ctrl.setStage(primaryStage);
```